# video problem on chrome html/css audio/video problem

Tags: html, css

I added a video to the site, internet explorer and Edge are okay, but there is no sound in chrome.

HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
   <video autoplay loop>
      <source src="media/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 90vh;
   position:relative;
}

.main video{
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   object-fit: cover;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0; 
   border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Have you got an error in the console?

Comment: No there is no error

Comment: Can you please replicate this issue on jsbin, stackblitz, etc?

Comment: I think you can't even play the video, right?

Comment: just when muted property I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `id="video-background" plays-inline controls` in the `<video>` element.

There is no sound when playing a video because chrome doesn't love "autoplayed" videos with sounds for some security reasons, I think.
That's better than telling the user to change the settings to make the video playing with sound etc...
Now this will work in Chrome.
So your code will be:

```
<div class="main">
   <video loop id="video-background" plays-inline controls>
      <source src="media/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: it's work for me but I dont want controls I want autoplay when page loaded

Comment: @SkyPossible Unfortunately, you need to change some settings in chrome to make this possible.

Comment: @SkyPossible But hey you can add an `<audio>` element and make it playing automatically instead of facing the video problems!

Comment: Okay I understood

Comment: <audio autoplay loop>
                    <source src="media/main.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio> like this

Comment: No, not that way... I'll try to do it and I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: @SkyPossible What are you exactly trying to do? I think there isn't any reason to autoplay videos with audio on a website?